# My VB program is not managing to restore file in SQL server because path

Tags: sql-server, vb.net

I Have a vb program that executes a SQL server script to restore a database that was created in a different computer. This is my script...

```vb
Dim sql As String = $"RESTORE DATABASE [NewStock] FROM  DISK = N'C:\NewStock\NewStock.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5"
```

But when I run it it says:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\NewStock.mdf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
> File 'NewStock' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\NewStock.mdf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
> Directory lookup for the file "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\NewStock_log.ldf" failed with the operating system error 3(The system cannot find the path specified.).
> File 'NewStock_log' cannot be restored to 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\NewStock_log.ldf'. Use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location for the file.
> Problems were identified while planning for the RESTORE statement. Previous messages provide details.
> RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.'

I realized that it is complaining because the path of the SQL sever directory of the machine where the bak file was generated is different from the path in the destination machine. If I create manually the directory C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\ in the destination machine it works correctly. But not immediately because I got a denied access error and I had to change the permission of the DATA directory manually to allow write access. Then it worked.

The first message error suggested me to use WITH MOVE to identify a valid location. Then I tried this...

```vb
Dim sql As String = $"RESTORE DATABASE [NewStock] FROM  DISK = N'C:\NewStock\NewStock.bak' WITH  FILE = 1,  MOVE N'NewStock' TO N'C:\NewStock\NewStock.mdf',  MOVE N'NewStock_log' TO N'C:\NewStock\NewStock_log.ldf',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 5"
```

Then I ran in the very same permission value. Again if I change the permission of the C:\newstock folder manually it works. Unfortunately it is unacceptable because the reason we are doing this vb.net program is to make the life of our customers easier. Several of these users use SQL Express and dont even have SSMS in their computers and dont feel secure enough to change permissions and things like that.

I would like to know if there is a parameter I can add to the script that I tell to SQL server to override the original path and just save the new files in its default location.

Comment: Are you really still using SQL Server 2008R2? 2008 and 2008R2 has been completely unsupported for ~3 years now; it is *long* past time you upgraded.

Comment: You also probably need to ensure the path of the restore in your script isn't pointing to your local c:\drive?

I'd be inclined to script the restore in SSMS and use PowerShell invoke-sqlcmd to execute the script.

Comment: You need to find out default data and log file locations on your sql server. Depend on sql version you may need different approach.

Comment: @Larnu I am using SQL-Server 11 sir.

Comment: @JonTout thank you sir. I have no idea how to do this. I received the BAK file and have to use it. I will take a look.

Comment: @Arvo I understand sir.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `WITH MOVE` to tell the script where you want the files to physically be located on the destination machine:

```
RESTORE DATABASE [NewStock]
FROM DISK = N'C:\NewStock\NewStock.bak'
WITH MOVE 'NewStock' TO 'C:\Wherever\NewStock.mdf', 
MOVE 'NewStock_log' TO 'C:\Wherever\Log\NewStock_log.ldf',
RECOVERY, REPLACE
```

Comment: Thank you sir, but I tried WITH MOVE and then I got a access denied error. It only will work if I manually set the permissions of the destination folder to write manually. I tried to do it in vb but it didn't work.

Comment: Well, the folder permissions are a different issue, and should be a separate SO question (or a search, as it's likely been answered already).

Comment: If the VB application or script  isn't being on the server, you will need to configure UNC pathing in the MOVE sections.
https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/48037/restoring-database-to-unc-path-on-local-drive

Comment: @HardCode I agree sir. And I have searched but couldn't find anything that helps.

Comment: @JonTout Both application as well server are in the same machine. I am testing it directly from my own PC and trying to restore the backup in SQL-Express that is in  my own PC. The backup was created on other PC . Thank you sir!

Comment: @JonTout The problem is that my SQL-Sever express path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.SQLEXPRESS\MSSQL\DATA but when I run the script it keep trying to restore it to C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA. I was in hope that I could tell to the SQL-Server engine to restore the DB to the default destination path.

Comment: I would suggest manually running in sql management studio and once the paths had been set, there should be an option button called "Script" which will generate the sql commands and relevant paths. The once you've got the script, cancel the restore but execute that script to run the restore. If the script passes then you could then copy and amened in your vb script to see the restore works.